# Group list by sum of items

Tags: python

I'm looking for an effective way to group a list of integers into a list of lists, where the sum of the original items doesn't exceed a given number.

Please consider this list of integers:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2]
```

Which should be grouped so that the sum of the items never exceeds 3:

```
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], [3], [1, 1], [2]]
```

Comment: Algorithmically, that sounds straightforward. Just keeping a counter to do cumulative sums and resetting it when you hit >= 3 should do it, there won't be any faster way. I am pretty sure there is no 'standard' way to do it in python, if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Oh, you mean the [bin-packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem)

Comment: My first approach was a recursive function. But it felt overly complicated. Jochen Ritzel's solution which uses the yield statement has the effective beauty i was looking for. :)

Comment: @msw Interesting, that pretty much describes it. I had a feeling there must be a general term for this problem, but didn't know how it was called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def group(lst, limit):

    lim = 0
    grp = []

    for x in lst:
        if x + lim > limit:
            yield grp
            grp = []
            lim = 0

        grp.append(x)
        lim += x

    yield grp

print list(group([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2], 3))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
import itertools

def sumkey(n):
    sc = [0, 0] # sum, count => group by
    def keyfunc(x):
        sc[0] += x
        if sc[0] > n:
            sc[1] += 1
            sc[0] = x
        return sc[1]
    return keyfunc

xs = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2]
print([list(grp) for _, grp in itertools.groupby(xs, key=sumkey(3))])
```

In Python 3, `sumkey` could be written as following using [`nonlocal`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement):

```
def sumkey(n):
    sum_, count = 0, 0
    def keyfunc(x):
        nonlocal sum_, count
        sum_ += x
        if sum_ > n:
            count += 1
            sum_ = x
        return count
    return keyfunc
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most clever solution, but clean and simple enough:

```
def makeList(inList, n):
    aList = []
    while len(inList) > 0 and sum(aList) + inList[0] <= n :
        aList.append(inList.pop(0))

    return aList

def groupLists(inList, n, outList = []):
    if not n:
        raise ValueError("Please enter a positive integer")     
    while len(inList):
        outList.append(makeList(inList, n))
    return outList

print groupLists([1,1,1,1,2,2,1,3,1,1,2], 3)
```